# Python & clang: try...except statement not working for segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, clang

I am using libclang in Python to construct the AST of some source code. It occurs `segmentation fault(core dumped)` error for few files. Then I try the command in terminal `clang -fmodules -fsyntax-only -Xclang -ast-dump + file`. The error occurs, too. I believe clang crashed. (I do not know why, If you know how to solve it, please tell me). Because only few files cause this error. I want to ignore them and use try...except statement in python, but this statement does not work, this error still occurs and code running interrupts directly instead of running code in `except`. How can I delete the source file which causes error and continue to construct the AST for other files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`segmentation fault (core dumped)` means that the python interpreter has completely stopped (because of a bug in libclang probably).  `try...except` will not catch this.

Your best bet is to create a bug report for libclang, and attach a file which causes the error.

The only other options is to run libclang in a separate process for each file, and ignore any results if the process terminates.